# NEST adding context information to suggestions

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

does NEST support adding context information to suggestions in the current version (1.0.2)? According to this article (http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/elasticsearch-1-2-adding-context-suggestions/)

I didn't found a way how to achieve this by using fluent API.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet.  I just opened [#927](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/issues/927) to add support for this.  We'll try and get to it as soon as we can.